# Microsoft Word: Combine different column types in one page

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word

Is there a way in Microsoft Word to achieve the following lay out

Column 1  -------  Column 2

Full page width text

Column 1  -------  Column 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put a section break in between each portion.

Insert/Break/Continuous

With the formatting turned on it will look something like this:

[image]